# Comparing two spreadsheets and returning similarities

Tags: microsoft-excel, comparison

The challenge I am presented with is this:

I have two spreadsheets where I need to compare one column of data from each spreadsheet.

1. How do I do the comparison and have the same numbers from both represented in a third cleaned up spreadsheet or within the column itself? **Or**
2. How do I create a macro to eliminate the differences?

Comment: Well, there are many ways to go about this. Depends on how big your lists are, if you need it automated and so on. I would suggest combining the lists on one sheet and using excel's built in remove duplicates. You could of course automate this with VBA.

Comment: Do you need to account for inserted or deleted rows?

Comment: What code did you produce ? What is the programming question ?

Answer (score 0):

If your spreadsheets are structured in the same way (i.e. the worksheets are named the same in each workbook and the data to be compared is in the same row/column) then the excellent Beyond Compare can do a file comparison on the two and show you the differences. More info here:

http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=DataCompare